# Wildfly - migrate Wildfly from 8.2.1 to 21.0.0

Tags: migration, wildfly

I am using [wildfly migration server](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-server-migration)  to migrate my old wildFly(8.2.1) to the latest (21.0.0)
but I face that issue

this happens in migration **standalone.xml**

***UPDATE***

I get the error from `wildfly-server-migration-master/dist/standalone/target/jboss-server-migration/logs/migration.log`
its more readable now
seems to have an error in this part  ***jgroups***
but any hint on how to fix it

```
ERROR [management-operation] WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "jgroups"),
    ("stack" => "tcp"),
    ("transport" => "TCP")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0155: 'socket-binding' may not be null"
2020-11-03 02:32:11,219 FATAL [server] WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
2020-11-03 02:32:11,222 INFO  [as] WFLYSRV0050: WildFly Full 21.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 13.0.1.Final) stopped in 2ms
2020-11-03 02:32:11,225 ERROR [logger] Migration failed: org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigrationFailureException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEMB0022: Cannot invoke 'start' on embedded process
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:174) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.migrateConfig(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:151) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.migrateAllConfigs(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:120) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationsMigration$Task.run(ServerConfigurationsMigration.java:105) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.StandaloneServerMigration$1.run(StandaloneServerMigration.java:61) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.runTask(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:58) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.confirmTaskRun(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:50) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.console.UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.run(UserConfirmationServerMigrationTask.java:63) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.env.SkippableByEnvServerMigrationTask.run(SkippableByEnvServerMigrationTask.java:47) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.execute(TaskExecutionImpl.java:159) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:68) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskContextImpl.execute(TaskContextImpl.java:32) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerMigration.run(ServerMigration.java:45) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.WildFlyServer10.migrate(WildFlyServer10.java:40) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration$1.run(ServerMigration.java:153) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.ServerMigration.run(ServerMigration.java:160) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.cli.CommandLineServerMigration.main(CommandLineServerMigration.java:131) [jboss-server-migration-cli-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEMB0022: Cannot invoke 'start' on embedded process
    at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.invokeOnServer(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:100) [wildfly-embedded-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.start(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:58) [wildfly-embedded-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.management.impl.EmbeddedStandaloneServerConfiguration.startConfiguration(EmbeddedStandaloneServerConfiguration.java:89) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.management.impl.AbstractManageableServerConfiguration.start(AbstractManageableServerConfiguration.java:70) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.wfly10.config.task.ServerConfigurationMigration$1.run(ServerConfigurationMigration.java:96) [jboss-server-migration-wildfly10.0-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.migration.core.task.TaskExecutionImpl.run(TaskExecutionImpl.java:169) [jboss-server-migration-core-1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.10.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedProcessStartException: WFLYEMB0021: Cannot start embedded process
    at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory$StandaloneServerImpl.start(EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory.java:324) [wildfly-embedded-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
    at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.invokeOnServer(EmbeddedManagedProcessImpl.java:88) [wildfly-embedded-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: JBTHR00005: Operation failed
    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:253) [jboss-threads-2.3.3.Final.jar:2.3.3.Final]
    at org.wildfly.core.embedded.EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory$StandaloneServerImpl.start(EmbeddedStandaloneServerFactory.java:305) [wildfly-embedded-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapListener.bootFailure(BootstrapListener.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:426)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416) [wildfly-controller-11.1.1.Final.jar:11.1.1.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_221]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jgroups configuration is expecting a socket-binding element to define the address/port for connection.
According to https://docs.wildfly.org/21/wildscribe/subsystem/jgroups/stack/transport/TCP/index.html Sorry I don't have the model for WildFly 8.2.1 to 'see' which configuration you should change.

Comment: you right I added   socket-binding="jgroups-tcp to transport type="TCP" and it fixed it 
  <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>